# How to add a number in a declared with value?

Tags: javascript

if I have this:

```
 let endingDay = args.endDate.slice(8, args.endDate.length)
```

how can i add a number to it? i was trying to:

```
 if (startingDay > endingDay) { 
            let x = (endingDay + 30 ) - startingDay
            x = totalPrice
        }
```

but it didn't add up.

```
 let x = (endingDay + 30 ) - startingDay
 // instead of:
 (02 + 30) - 30
  32 - 30

 // it ends up like this:
 0230 - 30
```

it just combined but not adds up.

Comment: try converting endingDay and startingDay to number.
`(parseInt(endingDay) + 30) - parseInt(startingDay)`

Comment: put a plus infront of endingDay. Like this `+endingDay`

Comment: you save the day man, it works! thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to `parseInt`

```js
 let endingDay = '02'
 let startingDay = '01'
 
 let x = (endingDay + 30 ) - startingDay
 
 console.log(x)
 
 let y = (parseInt(endingDay,10) + 30 ) - parseInt(startingDay,10)
 console.log(y)
```

Alternatively:

```js
 let endingDay = '02'
 let startingDay = '01'

 let y = (endingDay*1 + 30 ) - startingDay*1
 console.log(y)
```

`str*1` will do the job.